# Fit an image a two-column style

Tags: graphics, two-column

How can I fit an image a two-column style confrence paperso that the image can appear in the middle of the page?

Can you please share an example code with me? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`h` works in two column just as one column

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{..}
\caption{..}
\end{figure}
```

will make the float appear "here" i.e. mid column if it fits at that point.