# How can I fit this image into the second column, below my text, in a two column format?

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, two-column

I need to fit an image into the second column of my document, but for some reason it keeps moving to the second page rather than in the second column.

***Here's my code:**

```
Texttexttexttext

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{image.png}
\caption{Current caption}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}
```

***Here's my LaTeX document currently:***

[image: My LaTeX document currently.]

I did some of my research on the Latex stack exchange on two column images. I visited this page: [Fit an image a two-column style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215708/fit-an-image-a-two-column-style), but even after I tested that out, the image's position didn't get any better - it actually moved down to the middle of the second page. When I used `\begin{figure*} ...\end{figure*}`, as suggested by [Place Image into two column LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522523/place-image-into-two-column-latex), the image moved to the center instead of on the first page right below my text. I added a `[H]` after the `{figure*}`, and the image disappeared completely.

I visited these links: [Overleaf Tutorial on Positioning Figures](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat). For the placement specifier, I've tried H, htp, h, h!, t!, t, hp - pretty much all the combinations. None of these combinations have worked. The closest I've gotten is using H (which is shown in the screenshot above), but its not on the first page like I would prefer.

I had trouble earlier with a previous image where the image size was too big and got pushed down but this time around, the image size doesn't show any errors and seems to fit right in the column.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: it is impossible to guess since you have not posted the code that produces that page break, presumably the figure does not fit in that column. note that `[H]` by design gives bad white space rather than float a figure to get a better page break.

Comment: try `\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}
\caption{Current caption}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The page break is automatically created. I have text 2 lines above the start of the figure, then an empty line, then the start of the figure. I'll edit my response to include that information (its difficult to explain in a comment)

Comment: @Zarko The image moves down to the middle of the 1st column on the second page. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: without an example document that shows the effect its going to be more or less impossible. It is easy for you to make an example as you have a document showing the problem, just delete everything unrelated to that page break change some words and post the resulting 2-page document

Comment: but looking at your image are you sure it would fit (given that there has to be some vertical space after the text then the image then the caption, you are making it almost impossible to help but it doesn't look like it fits to me

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Tried removing some information off the bottom of the figure image and changed it to ht as Zarko suggested. Earlier, it seemed like the image would fit in that space - maybe it was larger than I thought. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: the whole point of the `figure` environment is to allow the figure to float to avoid this problem. Why use `[H]` to disable that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106689/discussion-between-mystarypi-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: You should provide MWE in question, which will reproduce your problem.